# Message: Undefined index: hash

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am doing email verification for registration,i am getting error as i mention above.email is received successfully with hash code when i click then link it show the above error.

controller

```
public function verify() {

      $email = $_GET['email'];
      //$hash = $_GET['hash'];
      //echo $hash;exit;
     $result = $this->user_model->get_hash_value($_GET['email']); //get the hash value which belongs to given email from database
     //print_r($result);exit;
    if($result){ 
        //echo "welcome";exit;
        //$this->user_model->verify_user($email);
        if($result['hash']==$_GET['hash']){
            $this->user_model->verify_user($email);
        }
     }
}
```

model

```
public  function verify_user($email) {

                $data = array('is_verified' => 1);
                //print_r($data);exit;
                $this->db->where('email', $email);
                $this->db->update('user', $data);
}
```

what i want is,i want to compare the hash code from mail to database
if($result['hash']==$_GET['hash']),if this comparison true means update is_verified as 1 by using email.

//this is after edit

i tried both answer when i click the email link it shows error like this Fatal error: Call to a member function reslut_array() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\code2\application\controllers\user.php on line 306 Call Stack

if i print the $reslut value

public function verify() {

```
  $email = $_GET['email'];
  //$hash = $_GET['hash'];
  //echo $hash;exit;
 $result = $this->user_model->get_hash_value($_GET['email']); 
          print_r($result);exit;
if($result){ 
    //echo "welcome";exit;
    //$this->user_model->verify_user($email);
    if($result['hash']==$_GET['hash']){
        $this->user_model->verify_user($email);
    }
 }
```

}

then i getting like this

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [hash] => ed265bc903a5a097f61d3ec064d96d2e ) )

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function verify() {
    $email = $_GET['email'];
      //$hash = $_GET['hash'];
      //echo $hash;exit;
     $result = $this->user_model->get_hash_value($_GET['email']); //get the hash value which belongs to given email from database
     //print_r($result);exit;
    if($result){ 
        //echo "welcome";exit;
        //$this->user_model->verify_user($email);
        if($result[0]->hash==$_GET['hash']){
            $this->user_model->verify_user($email);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Try.. again I modified from `result_array()` to `row_array()`

Comment: You just replace your function ..and use the function I've modified.

Comment: yes i tried you anwer but it says atal error: Call to a member function row_array() on a non-object

Comment: Try again...I've modified again.

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C

Comment: Check again. I've change $result[0] to $result->hash

Comment: i got the answer,i am using array and object combination. if($result[0]->hash==$_GET['hash'])

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an array, so use `row()` or `row_array()`,

```
public function verify() {

  $email = $_GET['email'];
  $result = $this->user_model->get_hash_value($_GET['email'])->row(); 
  if($result){ 
    if($result->hash==$_GET['hash']){
        $this->user_model->verify_user($email);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: on my answer?? or your question??

Comment: i understant now i post in my question.

Comment: i am using code below, and 
 
error : Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: `print_r($result)` in controller and show what it is printing

Comment: i got the answer,i am using array and object combination,

Comment: if i have any doubt can i message you?

Comment: @FakkirmohamedSait accept the answer if it was helpful.